# static class self reference

Tags: c#, class, constructor, static, initialization

I'm trying to create a basic Foo class, and would like to duplicate the way a Color works, but I'm having trouble getting my head around it. E.g., I'd like to get this functionality ...

```
Color color = Color.Red;
```

for my Foo, and write

```
Foo x = Foo.y;
```

On a related note, and if I understand this correctly,

```
string s = "...";
```

is the same as

```
string s = new string("...".ToCharArray())
```

My questions is, can I define types that act and behave like that, so that I could have something like

`Bar w = 1`; which would be the same as `Bar w = new Bar(1)`;

Comment: Um, what's the language? (I'm guessing C#, but you should say so...)

Comment: And no, using a string literal isn't the same as creating a new string each time you go through that declaration. For your `Foo` part, just make a static field or property...

Comment: Oops - yes, sorry C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, it sounds like you just want static fields or properties, e.g.

```
public class Foo
{
    // A field...
    public static readonly Foo MyFunkyFooField = new Foo(...);

    // A property - which could return a field, or create a new instance
    // each time.
    public static Foo MyFunkyFooProperty { get { return ...; } }
}
```

For the second part, using a string literal is *not* like calling `new string(...)`, because it reuses the same string reference every time. You can't easily come up with your own behaviour like that.

You *can* create a custom implicit conversion from `int` to `Bar`, so that

```
Bar x = 1;
```

will work... but I would think twice about doing so. Implicit conversions often hurt code readability by hiding behaviour.

Comment: Could you take that a bit further (both parts)

E.g., given `Color x = Color.Red;` x is of type Colour ref, so it seems that Color.Red must also be of that type - and not, for example, an enum no?

Please also do show how it is possible to create a custom implicit conversion.  Thank you.

Comment: @peedurrr: What do you mean by "of type Colour ref"? It's just of type `Color`. When `Color` is an enum, the value of the field/property is a value of that enum type. When `Color` is a class, the value is a reference. It doesn't help that you've chosen a fairly ambiguous example - there are lots of `Color` types in the framework. Which one were you referring to? For the custom implicit conversion, there are lots of examples online - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx for example. (Also, please *one question* per post - it ends up being clearer that way.)

Comment: by Colour ref I meant Color ref, as in something that can be set to an instance of a Color using new.

Thanks also for the msdn link. Just what I wanted.

I shall re-post the second part of my question also.

Thanks again.

Comment: @peedurrr: That still doesn't make much sense to me. The type of `x` is just `Color`... in the same way as if you declare a field with `string name` that declares a field of type `string`. The value of that field is then a reference to a string, or null.

Comment: I'm not used to using fields for what I call variables. Is there a difference.  It just seems odd to me that one cannot write Color c; if it's truly a Color. The fact that it requires to be set (and null won't do) I don't fully understand, nor that, if set using, say, Color c = new Color(), that c.TypeOf().ToString() is different to ((new Color()).TypeOf().ToString()

I'm also not sure what the difference is between saying that c is a reference to a Color, and that c's value is a reference to a Color - which I think is what you're saying?

Comment: @peedurrr: You *can* write `Color c` - that will have a default value of null if it's a field (an instance or a static variable) but it won't be definitely assigned if it's a local variable. Do you mean `GetType()` instead of `TypeOf()`? It feels like you may be missing several different concepts here - and it doesn't help that we still don't know whether `Color` is a class or not...